# How high can I jump?

Tags: starbound

When I'm placing platforms, I'm not too sure how high I can place them and have them still be reachable.

How many block heights can I jump? (For reference, I know that by default, you can jump ten block heights.)

It would be awesome if you could also include in your answer:

- with blue stim pack / jump boost from food
- with Pulse Jump tech
- with Rocket Jump tech
- while in a Morphball
- while in a Mech
- combinations of the above, and anything else I've missed

Comment: Different planets have different gravity, so your jump height varies.

Comment: @Chippies assuming ship gravity then; 1.00.

Comment: Ship's gravity generally allows you jump about 4 blocks; the height of your character.

Comment: @aytimothy Are you sure? I can jump exactly ten blocks on my ship, as well as my homeworld, a 1.02 gravity ocean planet. This is holding the spacebar down, by the by.

Comment: Since platforms are placed on the background and you can jump through them I just place the cursor a bit below my feet and place the block when I'm at the apex of my jump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it varies by gravity. That being the case, I don't see the value in trying to compute jump height before placing platforms. A better approach would be to simply jump in an open area with a background, and placing a platform at the apex of the jump. Personally I place platforms closer together than necessary, since that requires less precision in a dangerous situation (if you're in an untamed area) and is easier for NPCs to navigate (if you're base-building).

No doubt you could get an exact answer, but since Starbound is in constant development, I would question the value of such an answer as opposed to a general approach that will always work.

Answer (score 2):

You can jump 11 blocks on your ship.
You can jump 19 blocks with blue stim pack
You can jump 20 blocks Pulse Jump
You can jump 27 blocks with Rocket Jump
You can jump 1 blocks with Morphball
You can jump 4 blocks with Mech
I don't know what food gives you jump boost, so I could not entirely complete the list.

Comment: You should always access the game to test your theory before answering.

Comment: Yeah I should, shouldn't I? I'll go and on my starbound now and test everything.

Comment: You can jump much higher with the bouncy and ground smash tech